# Likes of friends after API 1.0 expires

Tags: facebook, api

does anyone know if there will be any possibilities of requesting the friends of a user of my app with their likes, birthdays and names after the switch to API 2.0 of Facebook even if the friends don't use my app?
I have built an app that will need this to work.
Is there any way to request this with Facebook?

Thank you
Dennis

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible after v1.0 expires. You can´t get all friends anymore and friend permissions are deprecated. This is for privacy reasons (your App should not be able to get any data from users who did not authorize it) and there will be no workaround.

Check out the changelog for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have an API v1.0, which i would like to use to request the likes of friends. How can this be done in the PHP SDK? (i know it will expire, i just need it once)

Comment: how to deal with the php sdk is a whole new story, but the docs present some example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes - just authorize a user with "friends_likes" and call /friend-id/likes